# cpanel email account creation issue

Tags: php, function, web, cpanel, cpanel-xmlapi

I am trying to create an email account via script without logging into the cpanel. 
Here is the script I am using

http://www.zubrag.com/scripts/cpanel-create-email-account.php

Hosting provider is bluehost

I am getting this error

```
Cannot create email account. Possible reasons: "fopen" function allowed on your server, PHP is running in SAFE mode
```

safe mode is off in my ini file.

Here is the credential area that the script is using

```
// cPanel info
$cpuser = 'example.com'; // cPanel username
$cppass = 'my_cpanel_pass'; // cPanel password
$cpdomain = 'example.com'; // cPanel domain or IP
$cpskin = 'x';  // I have tried x and also bluehost here

// Default email info for new email accounts
// These will only be used if not passed via URL
$epass = 'my_cpanel_pass'; // email password
$edomain = 'example.com'; // email domain (usually same as cPanel domain above)
$equota = 20; // amount of space in megabytes
```

The following code is sending me the errors/warnings

```
$f = fopen ("http://$cpuser:$cppass@$cpdomain:2082/frontend/$cpskin/mail/doaddpop.html?email=$euser&domain=$edomain&password=$epass&quota=$equota", "r");
  if (!$f) {
    $msg = 'Cannot create email account. Possible reasons: "fopen" function allowed on your server, PHP is running in SAFE mode';
    break;
  }
```

The warning I'm getting is

```
Warning: fopen(http://...@example.com:2082/frontend/x/mail/doaddpop.html?email=asif.k&amp;domain=example.com&amp;password=SmallAn123!&amp;quota=20): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Access Denied in E:\Web Softs\wamp\www\clnt5\cpemail.php on line 81
```

If I print all the stuff between fopen() I get this

```
http://cpanel_user_name:my_cpanel_pass@example.com:2082/frontend/x/mail/doaddpop.html?email=asif.k&domain=mydomain.com&password=SmallAn123!&quota=20
```

I have googled a lot to fix this. Any help or an alternate script that can help me achieve this will be much appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't the URL be `http://cpanel_user_name:cpanel_password@example.com:2082/...`

Comment: sorry my mistake. The URL is in the same way you are specifying. but this script has really annoyed me

Comment: I don't think cPanel lets you automate adding mail accounts, I think you need to use WHM for this instead.

Comment: @Jamesking56 you mean its a dead end to this task ? couldn't it be achieved by the scripts like this one
http://codecanyon.net/item/cpanel-email-creator/168805

Answer (score 0):

If you have cpanel username and password then you should use cpanel API to create email accounts and for lot more functionalities too rather than these get request.

```
        require_once 'xmlapi.php';
        $xmlapi = new \xmlapi($cpanel_domain);

        $xmlapi->password_auth($cpanel_username,$cpanel_password);

        $xmlapi->set_port('your domain port will be here');

        $api2args = array();                            
        $result = $xmlapi->api1_query($cpanel_password, 'CustInfo', 'getemail', $api2args);
         // until here you will get confirmation of your connected cpanel with cpanel api
         // then create cpanel as below
          $api2args = array(
            'domain'          => $domain, 
            'email'           => $email_address_to_create, 
            'password'        => $email_password,
            'quota'           => '2048',    // quota for email you want to set                          
            );
            $result = $xmlapi->api2_query($cpanel_username, 'Email', 'addpop', $api2args);

        if(isset($result->error) && $result->error!=""){                
            // error can be recorded here
        }
        else{
           // email account get created
        }
```